# Execute user's placed bets automatically in Spring?

Tags: spring, web, logic

I'm creating a gambling website for my portfolio. On this website, users can bet on the future prices of crypto tokens. Essentially, they can bet on whether the price will go up or down, and after 24 hours, their balance will be awarded or deducted accordingly.

So far, I have implemented various additional features such as fetching crypto tokens data from an API, adding other games, implementing authentication, and more. However, I dont know how to automatically check the users' bets and execute them.

Currently, I'm using MySQL and have implemented websocket to provide real-time updates to the user's wallet. However, I'm unsure about how to handle the execution of bets after the 24-hour timespan. One idea I had was to create a scheduled MySQL query that runs every hour, checks the timespan of each user's bet, and if 24 hours have passed, takes appropriate action (do some calculations on his balance..etc), but I believe this approach may be inefficient and resource-intensive, especially if there are thousands of users.